# error C2733 second C linkage of overloaded function 'function' not allowed

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I am trying to compile old cpp MFC project in Visual Studio 2010 pro.

It uses dll which is compiled using Labview, and I am adding this information because I don't know what is causing the error message..

The error messages show up on multiple functions, all same error type.

```
error C2733: second C linkage of overloaded function 'function name' not allowed.
```

the 'function name' includes:  'StrCatW', 'StrCmpNW', 'StrCmpW', 'StrCpyNW', and 'StrCpyW'

I found a [similar case](http://stefanobolli.blogspot.com/2010/10/compiler-error-c2733-second-c-linkage.html) on the web.

Although the suggestion in the link didn't solve in my case and I still see the same error messages.

Thanks in advance for anyone trying to help.

Comment: Looks like the functions `StrCatW`, 'StrCmpNW`, etc. are either linked more than once or they are include in more than one file *without* being declared as `inline`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews The error is not saying that there is more than one definition of the same function but rather that there are more than one overloads with the same name. The problem in this case is that because of the C linkage, name mangling is disabled, and you cannot have to symbols with the exact same name referring to different functions.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I have no experience with MFC, anyway i'll try to answer.
Such error message appears when an `extern "C"` function is declared with a different set of parameters. For example:

```
extern "C" int myfunc(int);
extern "C" int myfunc(char);
```

In your case, the two declarations are probably related to `char*`:

```
extern "C" char* StrCatW(char*, char*);
extern "C" wchar_t* StrCatW(wchar_t*, wchar_t*);
```

Try turning off Unicode support in your solution: i guess, if the dll is really old, it somehow declares `StrCatW` with `char*` arguments, conflicting with some other declaration.

If that doesn't help, turn on preprocessed output (`/E` compiler switch, as far as i recall) - it will output a very large file, so look for `StrCatW` in it, maybe it will give you some clue on what is going on.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions.. Turned off Unicode support and didn't work so I am going to try the preprocessed output and see what's going on

Comment: Hi As I turn on the preprocess (/P in VS 2010), I see LINK error asking for stdafx.obj, which is the obj file of first cpp in my source files list. I found MSDN error explanation which seems related to what you suggested.. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z9es6ec(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: I solved the problem simply by commenting out from header file the functions in the list of error 'second C linkage'

Comment: In my case, the error was because I declared a function in my DLL as `extern "C" {DECLDIR void GetSetFrameFunctionPointers( void (*myfunc)(int i) );}` in the header file and implemented it as `extern "C" {DECLDIR void GetSetFrameFunctionPointers( void (*myfunc)() );}` in the cpp file. The `int i` was missing, and that had caused the error.

Comment: yeah, I guess that will also be in category of what David Rodríguez - dribeas commented on the first thread.  In your case, I assume C/C++ takes in no-argument function as valid however that will still create error because name mangling is disabled in C linkage.

Comment: In my case the 'extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)' function declared in my dll conflicted with a Windows function with the same name. Changing to a less common name solved the problem.