# Why "second C linkage of overloaded function" is not allowed?

Tags: c++, c, dll, extern

I converted my C++ dll to C dll:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
    extern "C" {
#endif

MY_EXPORT int  my_func();
MY_EXPORT void my_func(int n);

#ifdef __cplusplus
    }
#endif
```

Everything worked fine without `extern C` declaration. With this declaration I got

> error C2733: second C linkage of overloaded function 'my_func' not
>   allowed

Why is it not allowed to export overloaded functions from C-style dll ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/479207/function-overloading-in-c

Comment: C linkage implies no name-mangling. hence they would get the same name.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error C2733 second C linkage of overloaded function 'function' not allowed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7840203/error-c2733-second-c-linkage-of-overloaded-function-function-not-allowed)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

C does not allow to overload functions. That is C does not support overloading. It is a feature of C++.