# Second C Linkage of Overloaded Function for a Standard Library stdio.h

Tags: c++, c, overloading, linkage

In my research, I have read that C does not support overloading.  However, this application is using C++, not C.  I also ***can't modify*** stdio.h.  The error was created when I tried to move an application/project that was written in Visual Studio 2003 to Visual Studio 2010.

I am getting the errors:

> error C2733: second C linkage of overloaded function '_tempnam_dbg' not allowed    c:...\stdio.h

and

> error C2733: second C linkage of overloaded function '_wtempnam_dbg' not allowed   c:...\include\stdio.h

The code which causes the corresponding errors:

```
_Check_return_ _CRTIMP char * __cdecl _tempnam(_In_opt_z_ const char * _DirName, _In_opt_z_ const char * _FilePrefix);

...

_Check_return_ _CRTIMP wchar_t * __cdecl _wtempnam(_In_opt_z_ const wchar_t * _Directory, _In_opt_z_ const wchar_t * _FilePrefix);
```

I have read from [this SO solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7840203/error-c2733-second-c-linkage-of-overloaded-function-function-not-allowed) that *"Such error message appears when an extern 'C' function is declared with a different set of parameters."*.
**Edited:**
This being said, this is the only area in my solution that contains anything about `tempnam` and `wtempnam`.

Comment: "I can only find one declaration of this function in my entire solution" -- if you can find *any* declaration of these functions in your own code then it is probably a mistake.  You should be relying exclusively on the standard headers for declarations of functions from the standard library.

Comment: Are you trying to compile a file other than a `.cpp` file? From what I can find online, it seems that you're right about this being a C error rather than C++. Also, you shouldn't redefine a function from the standard library without good reason. That can definitely cause issues.

Comment: Please excuse me, as I was not correct before when I said "I can only find one declaration of this function".  The code shown is the only relevant code I can find and that is taken from stdio.h

Comment: The compiler thinks the two functions named are overloaded, which means it must be seeing more than one declaration of each name.  Standard conditional inclusion directives *ought* to prevent that happening if the only declarations involved are in the standard headers.  Possibly VS2010's C library is buggy, though.  As a wild guess, such a bug might manifest if at one place you include `stdio.h` but at another you include `cstdio`.  Whether that explains it or not, it wouldn't be a bad idea to switch to `cstdio` everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all stdio.h is part of C not C++, so anything included in there is probably in between `extern "C"` which means that C symbols are not mangled and therefore function overloading is not possible.

In C++, function overloading uses name mangling (based on name and parameter list) to work so if you have `_tempnam(const char*, const char*)` declared in two places it is still not going to work because the parameter list is the same.

Look up C++ name mangling.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling

Also it looks like tempnam is a Microsoft only function.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs3e7355.aspx

Because I can only find tmpnam in the C standard library.
http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/tmpnam

Answer (score 4):

Since you're using C++ instead of C, you should `#include <cstdio>` instead of `#include <stdio.h>`.  Simiarly for stdlib, stdarg, string, math, errno, stdint, and others.  Those have the proper declarations to work properly in C++.